# CSS Round corners In IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css, rounding

I am using [this](http://www.htmlremix.com/css/curved-corner-border-radius-cross-browser) **.htc** logic to make my content tabs rounded but its not working. My tab structure looks like this.

```
<li id="profiletab1" class="selected">
   <a href="#">Overview</a>
</li>
<li id="profiletab2" class="">
   <a href="#">Overview</a>
</li>
...
```

css code for this

```
color: #4f4f4f;
 height: 35px;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0px 18px 0px 19px;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 35px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
behavior: url(border-radius.htc);

background: #e7e7e7;
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 bottom, from(#e7e7e7), to(#cccccc));
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#e7e7e7, #cccccc);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(#e7e7e7, #cccccc);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(#e7e7e7, #cccccc);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(#e7e7e7, #cccccc);
 background: linear-gradient(#e7e7e7, #cccccc);
 -pie-background: linear-gradient(#e7e7e7, #cccccc);
 border-right: 1px solid #b1b1b1;
```

Comment: what is profiletab class's attribute, please mention them.

Comment: If your using older versions of IE it wont render CSS3 if that is what you are using

Comment: What browsers have you tested/are you using? You should not need an htc file for anything other than older versions of IE.

Comment: I am not seeing it rounded in IE7,8

Comment: please add some information e review your code, it seems that something is missing (which css style is applied on profiletab2? Which one on profiletab1?)

Comment: Does .htc applies only to div's? I am here using <a> tag

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
behavoir:url(PIE.htc)
```

at the end of the class

Answer (score 0):

IE does not support CSS 3 until the IE 9

to use

```
border-radius
```

in css,

add

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />`

and

if you want to have them in IE 7/8,

you will need some sort of help with some javascript library.

e.g. http://css3pie.com/

Comment: I am already using same thing like css3 pie, but could not get solution.

Answer (score 0):

Is it working in any IE browser? Also double check the path of your .htc file

I am using the PIE.htc method and my CSS is something like this.

```
#maincol #content {
float:left;
background-color:#FFF;
width:100%;
height:399px;
-moz-border-radius:0 0 10px 10px;
-webkit-border-radius:0 0 10px 10px;
border-radius:0 0 10px 10px; 
behavior: url(../css/PIE.htc);
}
```

Also I have tested and verified that it works in all versions of IE. All I had to do was put the pie.htc file in my CSS folder and then add the behavior to the elements that I wanted to round the corners on.